# Creating a PHP Sign up form

Tags: php, mysql, registration

I am creating a sign up script, in the past i have used a sign up form with a processing file that inserts it and then that leads to the members area.  Is there a way on pressing the submit button i can create the account and give any error messages right away instead of using a process php file? It will be helpful if i can get a sample code as i am sort of new to this.

I am new to programming so ajax/javascript are something i am not well versed with right now, is there a way i can do simple on same page verification like www.foursquare.com/signup does

Thanks.

Clarification:

I am looking to create a sign up script that will show errors on the same page.  A process very similar to foursquare.com/signup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. The way to do it is by using JavaScript validation. Take a look at jQuery, a javascript library, and its many plugins that do validation (like this one: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation)

Javascript is a scripting language that your browser executes. You can do the validation on the browser side, without uploading anything to the PHP server component.

One critical thing to note is that you CANNOT rely on Javascript to do all your validation. Someone malicious can circumvent your client-side logic. So make sure to replicate all the validation logic on the server side.

Comment: I am new to programming so ajax/javascript are something i am not well versed with right now, is there a way i can do simple on same page verification like www.foursquare.com/signup does

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can by using AJAX (a Javascript technology). It allows you to send a background request to your process.php, which will create the account and return the result without the page being refreshed. You can then display an error on the same page, or redirect to the members area.

You can even do some basic checks (invalid characters, username too short) in Javascript, so there is no need for a request at all as long as the name is not valid.

It is advisable however, to implement both, so that people without Javascript can still sign up. This is done very easy by hooking the OnSubmit event of the form in Javascript and implement the AJAX call there. If there is no Javascript, the event will not be hooked and the form will be posted the regular way. Process.php will need all the checks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying you want to be able to process the form without it refreshing the page? The only way would be to use Ajax to submit the form and process the request, then update the HTML based on a JSON response, for example.

If you're meaning to say that you want to not have to use another php file to process the form, then just set the form action to the same php file that the form resides on and check if the form has been posted on that page.

If neither of those is what you're talking about then please update your question with more information about what you're looking to achieve.